# Problems with SVG styling

Tags: html, css, svg

I have an SVG and i'm trying to do 2 things.

I wanted to center it in the .left div, i tried to use:

```
Display:flex;
Justify-content: center;
Align-items: center;
```

---

```
text-align: center;
```

---

```
display: block;
margin: auto;
```

none of them worked for me in this case.

besides that, i'm also trying to resize it when it gets to a smaller viewport, but when i try to set the only way i know to do it

```
width: 70%;
height: 70%;
```

the SVG starts to disappear instead of resizing it

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans&family=Poppins:wght@300;400;600&display=swap");

:root {
  --Violet: hsl(257, 40%, 49%);
  --SoftMagenta: hsl(300, 69%, 71%);
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

main {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: var(--Violet);
  background-image: url("/assets/images/bg-desktop.svg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding: 2rem 3rem 1rem;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 8%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  padding-left: 1rem;
}

header svg {
  width: 75%;
  height: 75%;
  padding-left: 0.6rem;
}

section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 77%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.left {
  width: 57%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: 2.7rem;
  padding-right: 2.5rem;
}

.left svg {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.right {
  height: 100%;
  width: 43%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  padding-right: 2.5rem;
}

.heading {
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 2.3rem;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  margin-bottom: 0.8rem;
}

.top {
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
}

.bottom {
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
}

.sub-heading {
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
}

.button {
  background-color: white;
  color: var(--Violet);
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0.7rem 3.5rem;
  border-radius: 50px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.2s ease;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: var(--SoftMagenta);
  color: white;
}

footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 15%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
}

footer ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

footer ul li {
  padding: 0.5rem 0.6rem;
  list-style-type: none;
  border-radius: 40px;
  border: solid 1px white;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.2s ease;
}

footer ul li:hover {
  border-color: var(--SoftMagenta);
  color: var(--SoftMagenta);
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1340px) {
  .left svg {
    height: 70%;
    width: 70%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./images/favicon-32x32.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/styles/styles.css">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/2140c62525.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <title>Frontend Mentor | Huddle landing page</title>

</head>

<body>
  <main>
    <header>
      <div class="menu">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="264" height="49pt" viewBox="0 0 198 49">
          <g fill="#FFF">
            <path
              d="M31.184 10.285c-5.91-.004-12.075 1.328-18.301 3.055-.79.16-1.563.676-1.969 1.316-.375.602-.512 1.207-.629 1.844-.605 3.387-.531 6.715-.406 10.398.027.844.156 1.848.547 2.454.414.613 1.117 1.003 1.96 1.132 1.083.164 2.16.29 3.239.403l-.238 6.656c-.04.527.222.969.543 1.223.289.218.61.316.937.34.656.05 1.43-.235 1.813-.961 1.68-3.235 2.734-4.66 4.832-6.81 5.48.138 10.261-.167 15.672-.57 1.914-.046 3.23-1.613 3.578-2.863 1.035-3.238 1.199-7.234 1.308-11.277.047-1.602-.508-3.172-1.492-4.004-.937-.758-2.066-1.031-3.105-1.312-2.883-.653-5.766-1.004-8.29-1.024zm7.875 2.531c1.039.282 1.957.555 2.53 1.024.966 1.023.934 1.707.923 2.812-.11 3.918-.297 7.723-1.184 10.606-.383 1.074-1.043 1.84-2.3 1.953-5.516.41-10.301.727-15.844.566a.792.792 0 0 0-.582.23c-2.329 2.352-3.52 3.99-5.297 7.407-.04.078-.13.125-.242.133-.07-.004-.102-.063-.106-.113l.238-7.22a.804.804 0 0 0-.695-.8 73.176 73.176 0 0 1-3.871-.477c-.555-.082-.758-.234-.91-.46-.266-.633-.262-1.024-.281-1.63-.126-3.656-.184-6.847.374-10.023.055-.472.231-.953.418-1.351.31-.485.782-.555 1.258-.688 6.086-1.68 12.04-2.937 17.649-2.941 2.75.097 5.633.375 7.922.972zm-21.024 6.192c-.84 1.004-.758 2.367-.11 3.281.34.48.868.863 1.509.95.836.07 1.367-.27 1.937-.657 1.035-.898 1.14-2.469.352-3.605a2.184 2.184 0 0 0-1.696-.946c-.898.008-1.507.407-1.992.977zm9.07-.82c-.835.027-1.511.605-1.925 1.23-.47.71-.746 1.605-.364 2.484.735 1.684 3.274 1.664 4.286-.05.464-.79.347-1.688 0-2.336-.348-.653-.872-1.184-1.633-1.305a1.934 1.934 0 0 0-.364-.023zm7.364.156a2.895 2.895 0 0 0-.778.086c-1.004.27-1.859 1.304-1.73 2.629.066.668.371 1.32.926 1.765.554.45 1.355.649 2.203.477.972-.2 1.578-.985 1.777-1.742.203-.758.153-1.528-.316-2.153a2.655 2.655 0 0 0-2.082-1.062zM19.96 19.586c.184.004.332.062.484.281.34.492.246 1.235-.097 1.535-.34.297-.555.325-.707.305-.149-.023-.301-.125-.438-.316-.258-.368-.336-.961.008-1.387.18-.242.516-.395.75-.418zm7.254.172c.027.004.355.195.512.488.156.293.183.563.035.813-.442.75-1.38.546-1.52.222-.055-.125-.015-.625.242-1.011.258-.391.578-.536.73-.512zm8.082.57c.047.067.164.492.074.828-.09.34-.238.547-.598.621-.46.098-.718 0-.914-.156-.191-.156-.324-.422-.351-.707-.07-.703.183-.867.586-.973.465-.117.992.086 1.203.387zm0 0M53.867 13.434a.892.892 0 0 1 .219-.536.665.665 0 0 1 .535-.238h5.223c.176 0 .36.074.547.219a.68.68 0 0 1 .28.555v8.336h8.74v-8.336a.768.768 0 0 1 .793-.773h5.151c.235 0 .438.058.614.175.176.117.265.305.265.562V38c0 .258-.078.45-.23.578-.152.129-.352.195-.598.195h-5.203a.845.845 0 0 1-.574-.195c-.145-.129-.219-.32-.219-.578v-9.988h-8.738V38c0 .246-.078.438-.238.57-.157.137-.371.203-.641.203h-5.172c-.492 0-.742-.23-.754-.687zm48.11 25.039a1.1 1.1 0 0 1-.485.246 2.422 2.422 0 0 1-.484.054h-2.656c-.211 0-.391-.039-.543-.113a1.197 1.197 0 0 1-.387-.308 1.842 1.842 0 0 1-.266-.442 3.71 3.71 0 0 1-.176-.508l-.543-2.25c-.175.364-.433.774-.765 1.239a6.65 6.65 0 0 1-1.274 1.3 7.077 7.077 0 0 1-1.847 1.02c-.715.277-1.535.414-2.461.414-1.336 0-2.55-.258-3.64-.773a8.372 8.372 0 0 1-2.79-2.11c-.765-.89-1.36-1.933-1.781-3.12a11.327 11.327 0 0 1-.633-3.81V17.797c0-.445.094-.785.29-1.012.19-.23.5-.344.921-.344h4.063c.503 0 .847.086 1.039.254.187.172.28.5.28.996v11.446c0 .504.114.98.34 1.433a4.282 4.282 0 0 0 2.18 2.012c.477.2.961.3 1.454.3.421 0 .859-.1 1.308-.3.453-.2.867-.465 1.25-.797.379-.336.695-.73.942-1.18.246-.453.367-.93.367-1.433v-11.43c0-.199.039-.398.113-.597a.963.963 0 0 1 .344-.457c.152-.094.297-.16.43-.196.136-.035.292-.05.468-.05h3.973c.504 0 .867.12 1.09.367.222.246.336.578.336.988v19.676c0 .222-.051.425-.153.613a1.091 1.091 0 0 1-.41.441zm20.414-2.426c-.317.316-.668.656-1.047 1.02-.383.363-.801.703-1.258 1.019-.457.316-.95.578-1.477.785a4.714 4.714 0 0 1-1.707.305c-1.593 0-3.062-.297-4.402-.895a10.537 10.537 0 0 1-3.465-2.453c-.969-1.039-1.722-2.262-2.27-3.668-.542-1.406-.816-2.918-.816-4.535 0-1.629.274-3.145.817-4.547.546-1.398 1.3-2.617 2.27-3.656a10.403 10.403 0 0 1 3.464-2.445c1.34-.59 2.809-.887 4.402-.887a5.32 5.32 0 0 1 1.77.281 6.49 6.49 0 0 1 1.457.719c.441.297.844.625 1.215.996.367.367.719.73 1.047 1.082v-8.04c0-.374.113-.69.34-.948.23-.258.574-.387 1.03-.387h3.958c.152 0 .312.035.48.098.172.066.328.156.469.273.14.117.254.258.34.422.09.164.133.344.133.543v26.289c0 .902-.473 1.355-1.422 1.355h-3.45c-.234 0-.414-.03-.542-.09a.826.826 0 0 1-.325-.253 1.64 1.64 0 0 1-.238-.422c-.07-.168-.16-.367-.266-.59zm-10.114-8.422c0 .773.121 1.496.364 2.172a5.142 5.142 0 0 0 1.027 1.75c.445.492.98.883 1.61 1.168.624.289 1.32.43 2.081.43.75 0 1.457-.133 2.121-.403.66-.27 1.239-.64 1.73-1.117a5.616 5.616 0 0 0 1.188-1.68 5.541 5.541 0 0 0 .5-2.074v-.246c0-.75-.14-1.465-.421-2.145a5.712 5.712 0 0 0-1.168-1.793 5.555 5.555 0 0 0-1.758-1.222 5.326 5.326 0 0 0-2.192-.45c-.761 0-1.457.15-2.082.45a4.827 4.827 0 0 0-1.609 1.223 5.497 5.497 0 0 0-1.027 1.792 6.341 6.341 0 0 0-.364 2.145zm37.278 8.422c-.317.316-.664.656-1.047 1.02-.38.363-.797.703-1.254 1.019-.457.316-.95.578-1.48.785a4.693 4.693 0 0 1-1.704.305c-1.593 0-3.062-.297-4.406-.895a10.561 10.561 0 0 1-3.46-2.453c-.97-1.039-1.727-2.262-2.27-3.668-.547-1.406-.817-2.918-.817-4.535 0-1.629.27-3.145.817-4.547a11.299 11.299 0 0 1 2.27-3.656 10.427 10.427 0 0 1 3.46-2.445c1.344-.59 2.813-.887 4.406-.887.645 0 1.235.094 1.766.281a6.52 6.52 0 0 1 1.46.719c.438.297.845.625 1.212.996.37.367.719.73 1.047 1.082v-8.04c0-.374.117-.69.343-.948.23-.258.57-.387 1.028-.387h3.957c.152 0 .312.035.484.098.168.066.324.156.465.273.14.117.258.258.344.422.09.164.133.344.133.543v26.289c0 .902-.477 1.355-1.426 1.355h-3.446c-.234 0-.417-.03-.546-.09a.855.855 0 0 1-.325-.253 1.764 1.764 0 0 1-.238-.422c-.07-.168-.156-.367-.262-.59zm-10.11-8.422c0 .773.121 1.496.36 2.172a5.214 5.214 0 0 0 1.03 1.75c.446.492.981.883 1.606 1.168.63.289 1.325.43 2.086.43a5.55 5.55 0 0 0 2.118-.403 5.36 5.36 0 0 0 1.734-1.117 5.616 5.616 0 0 0 1.187-1.68 5.541 5.541 0 0 0 .5-2.074v-.246a5.656 5.656 0 0 0-1.594-3.938 5.468 5.468 0 0 0-1.757-1.222 5.295 5.295 0 0 0-2.188-.45c-.761 0-1.457.15-2.086.45a4.851 4.851 0 0 0-1.605 1.223 5.577 5.577 0 0 0-1.031 1.792 6.436 6.436 0 0 0-.36 2.145zm21.54-16.477c0-.375.093-.691.28-.949.188-.258.512-.386.97-.386h4.308c.117 0 .238.03.367.097.13.063.25.152.36.27.113.117.207.258.28.422.079.164.118.347.118.546v26.27c0 .445-.129.785-.379 1.012-.254.23-.578.343-.976.343h-4.079c-.457 0-.78-.113-.968-.343-.188-.227-.282-.567-.282-1.012zm29.609 24.954a11.67 11.67 0 0 1-3.48 2.222c-1.29.535-2.657.801-4.098.801-1.606 0-3.121-.293-4.551-.879a11.8 11.8 0 0 1-3.766-2.437 11.656 11.656 0 0 1-2.566-3.664c-.633-1.407-.95-2.938-.95-4.59 0-1.032.126-2.032.38-3 .25-.965.609-1.871 1.07-2.715a11.743 11.743 0 0 1 1.687-2.332 10.792 10.792 0 0 1 4.899-2.996c.96-.282 1.976-.422 3.043-.422.972 0 1.914.129 2.832.387a11.04 11.04 0 0 1 4.781 2.777 11.35 11.35 0 0 1 1.723 2.156c.48.777.851 1.61 1.117 2.496.262.883.394 1.797.394 2.735 0 .609-.007 1.105-.027 1.492-.016.387-.105.695-.27.926-.164.226-.437.386-.82.472-.379.09-.941.133-1.68.133h-12.66c.118.75.356 1.379.715 1.883.356.504.77.906 1.238 1.203.47.3.97.512 1.497.64a6.294 6.294 0 0 0 1.492.196c.422 0 .855-.043 1.3-.133a8.748 8.748 0 0 0 1.293-.351 7.331 7.331 0 0 0 1.145-.508c.344-.196.625-.399.836-.61.187-.152.348-.265.48-.34a.86.86 0 0 1 .434-.117c.152 0 .309.055.465.16.16.106.336.258.535.458l1.863 2.109c.13.152.211.289.246.414.036.121.055.25.055.379a.977.977 0 0 1-.195.605c-.13.168-.281.32-.457.45zm-8.457-14.649c-.457 0-.899.09-1.328.274-.426.18-.829.421-1.204.726a6.37 6.37 0 0 0-1.011 1.04 6.486 6.486 0 0 0-.73 1.179h8.988a10.599 10.599 0 0 0-.801-1.266 5.564 5.564 0 0 0-.985-1.023 4.295 4.295 0 0 0-1.265-.684c-.477-.164-1.031-.246-1.664-.246zm0 0" />
          </g>
        </svg>
      </div>
    </header>

    <section>
      <div class="left">
        <svg width="709" height="506" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
          <defs>
            <rect id="b" width="657.638" height="410.833" rx="13.701" />
            <filter x="-1.6%" y="-2.6%" width="103.2%" height="105.1%" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" id="a">
              <feOffset in="SourceAlpha" result="shadowOffsetOuter1" />
              <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="3.5" in="shadowOffsetOuter1" result="shadowBlurOuter1" />
              <feColorMatrix values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.145098039 0 0 0 0 0.180392157 0 0 0 0.181838768 0"
                in="shadowBlurOuter1" />
            </filter>
            <path d="M13.7 0h630.237c7.567 0 13.7 6.134 13.7 13.7v30.122H0V13.701C0 6.134 6.134 0 13.7 0z" id="d" />
            <filter x="-1.6%" y="-24%" width="103.2%" height="147.9%" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" id="c">
              <feOffset in="SourceAlpha" result="shadowOffsetOuter1" />
              <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="3.5" in="shadowOffsetOuter1" result="shadowBlurOuter1" />
              <feColorMatrix values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.145098039 0 0 0 0 0.180392157 0 0 0 0.181838768 0"
                in="shadowBlurOuter1" />
            </filter>
            <linearGradient x1="14.811%" y1="-22.362%" x2="75.996%" y2="119.406%" id="e">
              <stop stop-color="#FAD961" offset="0%" />
              <stop stop-color="#FF52C1" offset="100%" />
            </linearGradient>
            <linearGradient x1="50%" y1="0%" x2="50%" y2="100%" id="f">
              <stop stop-color="#00C7FA" offset="0%" />
              <stop stop-color="#007DFA" offset="100%" />
            </linearGradient>
            <linearGradient x1="28.973%" y1="0%" x2="90.2%" y2="111.244%" id="g">
              <stop stop-color="#FF52C1" offset="0%" />
              <stop stop-color="#9952FF" offset="100%" />
            </linearGradient>
            <path
              d="M11.691 0h195.83c6.457 0 11.692 5.234 11.692 11.691v327.195c0 6.457-5.235 11.692-11.692 11.692H11.691C5.234 350.578 0 345.343 0 338.886V11.691C0 5.234 5.234 0 11.691 0z"
              id="i" />
            <filter x="-4.1%" y="-2.6%" width="108.2%" height="105.1%" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" id="h">
              <feOffset in="SourceAlpha" result="shadowOffsetOuter1" />
              <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="3" in="shadowOffsetOuter1" result="shadowBlurOuter1" />
              <feColorMatrix values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.145098039 0 0 0 0 0.180392157 0 0 0 0.181838768 0"
                in="shadowBlurOuter1" />
            </filter>
            <path d="M11.691 0h195.83c6.457 0 11.692 5.234 11.692 11.691v25.704H0V11.691C0 5.234 5.234 0 11.691 0z"
              id="k" />
            <filter x="-4.1%" y="-24.1%" width="108.2%" height="148.1%" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" id="j">
              <feOffset in="SourceAlpha" result="shadowOffsetOuter1" />
              <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="3" in="shadowOffsetOuter1" result="shadowBlurOuter1" />
              <feColorMatrix values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.145098039 0 0 0 0 0.180392157 0 0 0 0.181838768 0"
                in="shadowBlurOuter1" />
            </filter>
          </defs>
          <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
            <g transform="translate(7 7)">
              <use fill="#000" filter="url(#a)" xlink:href="#b" />
              <use fill="#FFF" xlink:href="#b" />
              <use fill="#000" filter="url(#c)" xlink:href="#d" />
              <use fill="#00252E" xlink:href="#d" />
              <rect fill="#E1E8EE" x="49.323" y="13.694" width="137.008" height="16.433" rx="3.425" />
              <g transform="translate(591.874 15.064)" fill="#D8D8D8">
                <rect width="21.921" height="2.739" rx="1.369" />
                <rect y="5.478" width="21.921" height="2.739" rx="1.369" />
                <rect y="10.956" width="21.921" height="2.739" rx="1.369" />
              </g>
              <g transform="translate(49.323 94.492)">
                <ellipse fill="url(#e)" cx="32.882" cy="32.867" rx="32.882" ry="32.867" />
                <g transform="translate(104.126 8.217)" fill="#E1E8EE">
                  <rect width="78.78" height="10.956" rx="2.055" />
                  <rect y="21.911" width="274.016" height="5.478" rx="2.055" />
                  <rect y="32.867" width="251.181" height="5.478" rx="2.055" />
                  <rect y="43.822" width="228.346" height="5.478" rx="2.055" />
                </g>
                <g transform="translate(411.024 24.65)" fill="#A7B9C8">
                  <ellipse cx="8.22" cy="8.217" rx="8.22" ry="8.217" />
                  <ellipse cx="52.063" cy="8.217" rx="8.22" ry="8.217" />
                  <ellipse cx="30.142" cy="8.217" rx="8.22" ry="8.217" />
                  <ellipse cx="73.984" cy="8.217" rx="8.22" ry="8.217" />
                  <ellipse cx="95.906" cy="8.217" rx="8.22" ry="8.217" />
                </g>
              </g>
              <g transform="translate(49.323 187.614)">
                <ellipse fill="url(#f)" cx="30.827" cy="30.813" rx="30.827" ry="30.813" />
                <g transform="translate(102.07 6.162)" fill="#E1E8EE">
                  <rect width="78.78" height="10.956" rx="2.055" />
                  <rect y="21.911" width="274.016" height="5.478" rx="2.055" />
                  <rect y="32.867" width="251.181" height="5.478" rx="2.055" />
                  <rect y="43.822" width="228.346" height="5.478" rx="2.055" />
                </g>
                <g transform="translate(408.969 22.596)" fill="#A7B9C8">
                  <ellipse cx="8.22" cy="8.217" rx="8.22" ry="8.217" />
                  <ellipse cx="52.063" cy="8.217" rx="8.22" ry="8.217" />
                  <ellipse cx="30.142" cy="8.217" rx="8.22" ry="8.217" />
                </g>
              </g>
              <g transform="translate(49.323 285.53)">
                <ellipse fill="url(#g)" cx="30.827" cy="30.813" rx="30.827" ry="30.813" />
                <g transform="translate(102.07 6.162)" fill="#E1E8EE">
                  <rect width="78.78" height="10.956" rx="2.055" />
                  <rect y="21.911" width="274.016" height="5.478" rx="2.055" />
                  <rect y="32.867" width="251.181" height="5.478" rx="2.055" />
                  <rect y="43.822" width="228.346" height="5.478" rx="2.055" />
                </g>
                <g transform="translate(408.969 22.596)" fill="#A7B9C8">
                  <ellipse cx="8.22" cy="8.217" rx="8.22" ry="8.217" />
                  <ellipse cx="52.063" cy="8.217" rx="8.22" ry="8.217" />
                  <ellipse cx="30.142" cy="8.217" rx="8.22" ry="8.217" />
                  <ellipse cx="73.984" cy="8.217" rx="8.22" ry="8.217" />
                </g>
              </g>
            </g>
            <g transform="translate(483.787 149.422)">
              <use fill="#000" filter="url(#h)" xlink:href="#i" />
              <use fill="#FFF" xlink:href="#i" />
            </g>
            <g transform="translate(483.787 149.422)">
              <use fill="#000" filter="url(#j)" xlink:href="#k" />
              <use fill="#00252E" xlink:href="#k" />
            </g>
            <g transform="translate(505.8 162.277)">
              <rect fill="#E1E8EE" width="71.244" height="14.023" rx="2.923" />
              <g transform="translate(155.111 1.169)" fill="#D8D8D8">
                <rect width="18.706" height="2.337" rx="1.169" />
                <rect y="4.674" width="18.706" height="2.337" rx="1.169" />
                <rect y="9.349" width="18.706" height="2.337" rx="1.169" />
              </g>
            </g>
            <g transform="translate(505.709 223.372)">
              <ellipse fill="url(#e)" cx="10.276" cy="10.271" rx="10.276" ry="10.271" />
              <g transform="translate(31.512 2.054)" fill="#E1E8EE">
                <rect width="39.39" height="3.652" rx=".63" />
                <rect y="7.304" width="137.008" height="1.826" rx=".63" />
                <rect y="10.956" width="125.591" height="1.826" rx=".63" />
                <rect y="14.607" width="114.173" height="1.826" rx=".63" />
              </g>
            </g>
            <g transform="translate(505.709 317.864)">
              <ellipse fill="url(#e)" cx="10.276" cy="10.271" rx="10.276" ry="10.271" />
              <g transform="translate(31.512 2.054)" fill="#E1E8EE">
                <rect width="39.39" height="3.652" rx=".63" />
                <rect y="7.304" width="137.008" height="1.826" rx=".63" />
                <rect y="10.956" width="125.591" height="1.826" rx=".63" />
                <rect y="14.607" width="114.173" height="1.826" rx=".63" />
              </g>
            </g>
            <g transform="translate(505.709 254.87)">
              <g transform="translate(31.512 2.054)" fill="#E1E8EE">
                <rect width="39.39" height="3.652" rx=".63" />
                <rect y="7.304" width="137.008" height="1.826" rx=".63" />
                <rect y="10.956" width="125.591" height="1.826" rx=".63" />
                <rect y="14.607" width="114.173" height="1.826" rx=".63" />
              </g>
              <ellipse fill="url(#f)" cx="10.276" cy="10.271" rx="10.276" ry="10.271" />
            </g>
            <g transform="translate(505.709 349.361)">
              <g transform="translate(31.512 2.054)" fill="#E1E8EE">
                <rect width="39.39" height="3.652" rx=".63" />
                <rect y="7.304" width="137.008" height="1.826" rx=".63" />
                <rect y="10.956" width="125.591" height="1.826" rx=".63" />
                <rect y="14.607" width="114.173" height="1.826" rx=".63" />
              </g>
              <ellipse fill="url(#f)" cx="10.276" cy="10.271" rx="10.276" ry="10.271" />
            </g>
            <g transform="translate(505.709 286.367)">
              <g transform="translate(31.512 2.054)" fill="#E1E8EE">
                <rect width="39.39" height="3.652" rx=".63" />
                <rect y="7.304" width="137.008" height="1.826" rx=".63" />
                <rect y="10.956" width="125.591" height="1.826" rx=".63" />
                <rect y="14.607" width="114.173" height="1.826" rx=".63" />
              </g>
              <ellipse fill="url(#g)" cx="10.276" cy="10.271" rx="10.276" ry="10.271" />
            </g>
            <g transform="translate(505.709 380.858)">
              <g transform="translate(31.512 2.054)" fill="#E1E8EE">
                <rect width="39.39" height="3.652" rx=".63" />
                <rect y="7.304" width="137.008" height="1.826" rx=".63" />
                <rect y="10.956" width="125.591" height="1.826" rx=".63" />
                <rect y="14.607" width="114.173" height="1.826" rx=".63" />
              </g>
              <ellipse fill="url(#g)" cx="10.276" cy="10.271" rx="10.276" ry="10.271" />
            </g>
            <g transform="translate(505.709 412.356)">
              <ellipse fill="url(#e)" cx="10.276" cy="10.271" rx="10.276" ry="10.271" />
              <g transform="translate(31.512 2.054)" fill="#E1E8EE">
                <rect width="39.39" height="3.652" rx=".63" />
                <rect y="7.304" width="137.008" height="1.826" rx=".63" />
                <rect y="10.956" width="125.591" height="1.826" rx=".63" />
                <rect y="14.607" width="114.173" height="1.826" rx=".63" />
              </g>
            </g>
            <g transform="translate(505.709 443.853)">
              <g transform="translate(31.512 2.054)" fill="#E1E8EE">
                <rect width="39.39" height="3.652" rx=".63" />
                <rect y="7.304" width="137.008" height="1.826" rx=".63" />
                <rect y="10.956" width="125.591" height="1.826" rx=".63" />
                <rect y="14.607" width="114.173" height="1.826" rx=".63" />
              </g>
              <ellipse fill="url(#f)" cx="10.276" cy="10.271" rx="10.276" ry="10.271" />
            </g>
          </g>
        </svg>
      </div>
      <div class="right">
        <h1 class="heading"><span class="top">Build The Community</span><span class="bottom">Your Fans Will Love</span>
        </h1>
        <h2 class="sub-heading">
          Huddle re-imagines the way we build communities. You have a voice, but so does your audience.
          Create connections with your users as you engage in genuine discussion.
        </h2>
        <a href="https://matheustenorio.com#contact" class="button" target="_blank">Register</a>
      </div>
    </section>

    <footer>
      <ul>
        <li class="social-icons"><i class="fa-brands fa-github"></i></li>
        <li class="social-icons"><i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i></li>
        <li class="social-icons"><i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-up-right-from-square"></i></li>
      </ul>
    </footer>
  </main>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the width and the height attributes from `<svg>` and instead use the viewBox (in your case the value should be `viewBox="0 0 700 510"`) attribute it is much easier to control. If you then also remove the width and height defined in CSS (`width: 70%;height:70%`) the SVG will take up the available space. Now, you can control the size of the SVG by setting the width or the height of the parent element.

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans&family=Poppins:wght@300;400;600&display=swap");

:root {
  --Violet: hsl(257, 40%, 49%);
  --SoftMagenta: hsl(300, 69%, 71%);
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

main {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: var(--Violet);
  background-image: url("/assets/images/bg-desktop.svg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding: 2rem 3rem 1rem;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 8%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  padding-left: 1rem;
}

header svg {
  width: 75%;
  height: 75%;
  padding-left: 0.6rem;
}

section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 77%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.left {
  width: 57%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: 2.7rem;
  padding-right: 2.5rem;
}

.left svg {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.right {
  height: 100%;
  width: 43%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  padding-right: 2.5rem;
}

.heading {
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 2.3rem;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  margin-bottom: 0.8rem;
}

.top {
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
}

.bottom {
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
}

.sub-heading {
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
}

.button {
  background-color: white;
  color: var(--Violet);
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0.7rem 3.5rem;
  border-radius: 50px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.2s ease;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: var(--SoftMagenta);
  color: white;
}

footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 15%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
}

footer ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

footer ul li {
  padding: 0.5rem 0.6rem;
  list-style-type: none;
  border-radius: 40px;
  border: solid 1px white;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.2s ease;
}

footer ul li:hover {
  border-color: var(--SoftMagenta);
  color: var(--SoftMagenta);
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1340px) {
  .left svg {
    /*height: 70%;
    width: 70%;*/
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./images/favicon-32x32.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/styles/styles.css">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/2140c62525.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <title>Frontend Mentor | Huddle landing page</title>

</head>

<body>
  <main>
    <header>
      <div class="menu">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="264" height="49pt" viewBox="0 0 198 49">
          <g fill="#FFF">
            <path
              d="M31.184 10.285c-5.91-.004-12.075 1.328-18.301 3.055-.79.16-1.563.676-1.969 1.316-.375.602-.512 1.207-.629 1.844-.605 3.387-.531 6.715-.406 10.398.027.844.156 1.848.547 2.454.414.613 1.117 1.003 1.96 1.132 1.083.164 2.16.29 3.239.403l-.238 6.656c-.04.527.222.969.543 1.223.289.218.61.316.937.34.656.05 1.43-.235 1.813-.961 1.68-3.235 2.734-4.66 4.832-6.81 5.48.138 10.261-.167 15.672-.57 1.914-.046 3.23-1.613 3.578-2.863 1.035-3.238 1.199-7.234 1.308-11.277.047-1.602-.508-3.172-1.492-4.004-.937-.758-2.066-1.031-3.105-1.312-2.883-.653-5.766-1.004-8.29-1.024zm7.875 2.531c1.039.282 1.957.555 2.53 1.024.966 1.023.934 1.707.923 2.812-.11 3.918-.297 7.723-1.184 10.606-.383 1.074-1.043 1.84-2.3 1.953-5.516.41-10.301.727-15.844.566a.792.792 0 0 0-.582.23c-2.329 2.352-3.52 3.99-5.297 7.407-.04.078-.13.125-.242.133-.07-.004-.102-.063-.106-.113l.238-7.22a.804.804 0 0 0-.695-.8 73.176 73.176 0 0 1-3.871-.477c-.555-.082-.758-.234-.91-.46-.266-.633-.262-1.024-.281-1.63-.126-3.656-.184-6.847.374-10.023.055-.472.231-.953.418-1.351.31-.485.782-.555 1.258-.688 6.086-1.68 12.04-2.937 17.649-2.941 2.75.097 5.633.375 7.922.972zm-21.024 6.192c-.84 1.004-.758 2.367-.11 3.281.34.48.868.863 1.509.95.836.07 1.367-.27 1.937-.657 1.035-.898 1.14-2.469.352-3.605a2.184 2.184 0 0 0-1.696-.946c-.898.008-1.507.407-1.992.977zm9.07-.82c-.835.027-1.511.605-1.925 1.23-.47.71-.746 1.605-.364 2.484.735 1.684 3.274 1.664 4.286-.05.464-.79.347-1.688 0-2.336-.348-.653-.872-1.184-1.633-1.305a1.934 1.934 0 0 0-.364-.023zm7.364.156a2.895 2.895 0 0 0-.778.086c-1.004.27-1.859 1.304-1.73 2.629.066.668.371 1.32.926 1.765.554.45 1.355.649 2.203.477.972-.2 1.578-.985 1.777-1.742.203-.758.153-1.528-.316-2.153a2.655 2.655 0 0 0-2.082-1.062zM19.96 19.586c.184.004.332.062.484.281.34.492.246 1.235-.097 1.535-.34.297-.555.325-.707.305-.149-.023-.301-.125-.438-.316-.258-.368-.336-.961.008-1.387.18-.242.516-.395.75-.418zm7.254.172c.027.004.355.195.512.488.156.293.183.563.035.813-.442.75-1.38.546-1.52.222-.055-.125-.015-.625.242-1.011.258-.391.578-.536.73-.512zm8.082.57c.047.067.164.492.074.828-.09.34-.238.547-.598.621-.46.098-.718 0-.914-.156-.191-.156-.324-.422-.351-.707-.07-.703.183-.867.586-.973.465-.117.992.086 1.203.387zm0 0M53.867 13.434a.892.892 0 0 1 .219-.536.665.665 0 0 1 .535-.238h5.223c.176 0 .36.074.547.219a.68.68 0 0 1 .28.555v8.336h8.74v-8.336a.768.768 0 0 1 .793-.773h5.151c.235 0 .438.058.614.175.176.117.265.305.265.562V38c0 .258-.078.45-.23.578-.152.129-.352.195-.598.195h-5.203a.845.845 0 0 1-.574-.195c-.145-.129-.219-.32-.219-.578v-9.988h-8.738V38c0 .246-.078.438-.238.57-.157.137-.371.203-.641.203h-5.172c-.492 0-.742-.23-.754-.687zm48.11 25.039a1.1 1.1 0 0 1-.485.246 2.422 2.422 0 0 1-.484.054h-2.656c-.211 0-.391-.039-.543-.113a1.197 1.197 0 0 1-.387-.308 1.842 1.842 0 0 1-.266-.442 3.71 3.71 0 0 1-.176-.508l-.543-2.25c-.175.364-.433.774-.765 1.239a6.65 6.65 0 0 1-1.274 1.3 7.077 7.077 0 0 1-1.847 1.02c-.715.277-1.535.414-2.461.414-1.336 0-2.55-.258-3.64-.773a8.372 8.372 0 0 1-2.79-2.11c-.765-.89-1.36-1.933-1.781-3.12a11.327 11.327 0 0 1-.633-3.81V17.797c0-.445.094-.785.29-1.012.19-.23.5-.344.921-.344h4.063c.503 0 .847.086 1.039.254.187.172.28.5.28.996v11.446c0 .504.114.98.34 1.433a4.282 4.282 0 0 0 2.18 2.012c.477.2.961.3 1.454.3.421 0 .859-.1 1.308-.3.453-.2.867-.465 1.25-.797.379-.336.695-.73.942-1.18.246-.453.367-.93.367-1.433v-11.43c0-.199.039-.398.113-.597a.963.963 0 0 1 .344-.457c.152-.094.297-.16.43-.196.136-.035.292-.05.468-.05h3.973c.504 0 .867.12 1.09.367.222.246.336.578.336.988v19.676c0 .222-.051.425-.153.613a1.091 1.091 0 0 1-.41.441zm20.414-2.426c-.317.316-.668.656-1.047 1.02-.383.363-.801.703-1.258 1.019-.457.316-.95.578-1.477.785a4.714 4.714 0 0 1-1.707.305c-1.593 0-3.062-.297-4.402-.895a10.537 10.537 0 0 1-3.465-2.453c-.969-1.039-1.722-2.262-2.27-3.668-.542-1.406-.816-2.918-.816-4.535 0-1.629.274-3.145.817-4.547.546-1.398 1.3-2.617 2.27-3.656a10.403 10.403 0 0 1 3.464-2.445c1.34-.59 2.809-.887 4.402-.887a5.32 5.32 0 0 1 1.77.281 6.49 6.49 0 0 1 1.457.719c.441.297.844.625 1.215.996.367.367.719.73 1.047 1.082v-8.04c0-.374.113-.69.34-.948.23-.258.574-.387 1.03-.387h3.958c.152 0 .312.035.48.098.172.066.328.156.469.273.14.117.254.258.34.422.09.164.133.344.133.543v26.289c0 .902-.473 1.355-1.422 1.355h-3.45c-.234 0-.414-.03-.542-.09a.826.826 0 0 1-.325-.253 1.64 1.64 0 0 1-.238-.422c-.07-.168-.16-.367-.266-.59zm-10.114-8.422c0 .773.121 1.496.364 2.172a5.142 5.142 0 0 0 1.027 1.75c.445.492.98.883 1.61 1.168.624.289 1.32.43 2.081.43.75 0 1.457-.133 2.121-.403.66-.27 1.239-.64 1.73-1.117a5.616 5.616 0 0 0 1.188-1.68 5.541 5.541 0 0 0 .5-2.074v-.246c0-.75-.14-1.465-.421-2.145a5.712 5.712 0 0 0-1.168-1.793 5.555 5.555 0 0 0-1.758-1.222 5.326 5.326 0 0 0-2.192-.45c-.761 0-1.457.15-2.082.45a4.827 4.827 0 0 0-1.609 1.223 5.497 5.497 0 0 0-1.027 1.792 6.341 6.341 0 0 0-.364 2.145zm37.278 8.422c-.317.316-.664.656-1.047 1.02-.38.363-.797.703-1.254 1.019-.457.316-.95.578-1.48.785a4.693 4.693 0 0 1-1.704.305c-1.593 0-3.062-.297-4.406-.895a10.561 10.561 0 0 1-3.46-2.453c-.97-1.039-1.727-2.262-2.27-3.668-.547-1.406-.817-2.918-.817-4.535 0-1.629.27-3.145.817-4.547a11.299 11.299 0 0 1 2.27-3.656 10.427 10.427 0 0 1 3.46-2.445c1.344-.59 2.813-.887 4.406-.887.645 0 1.235.094 1.766.281a6.52 6.52 0 0 1 1.46.719c.438.297.845.625 1.212.996.37.367.719.73 1.047 1.082v-8.04c0-.374.117-.69.343-.948.23-.258.57-.387 1.028-.387h3.957c.152 0 .312.035.484.098.168.066.324.156.465.273.14.117.258.258.344.422.09.164.133.344.133.543v26.289c0 .902-.477 1.355-1.426 1.355h-3.446c-.234 0-.417-.03-.546-.09a.855.855 0 0 1-.325-.253 1.764 1.764 0 0 1-.238-.422c-.07-.168-.156-.367-.262-.59zm-10.11-8.422c0 .773.121 1.496.36 2.172a5.214 5.214 0 0 0 1.03 1.75c.446.492.981.883 1.606 1.168.63.289 1.325.43 2.086.43a5.55 5.55 0 0 0 2.118-.403 5.36 5.36 0 0 0 1.734-1.117 5.616 5.616 0 0 0 1.187-1.68 5.541 5.541 0 0 0 .5-2.074v-.246a5.656 5.656 0 0 0-1.594-3.938 5.468 5.468 0 0 0-1.757-1.222 5.295 5.295 0 0 0-2.188-.45c-.761 0-1.457.15-2.086.45a4.851 4.851 0 0 0-1.605 1.223 5.577 5.577 0 0 0-1.031 1.792 6.436 6.436 0 0 0-.36 2.145zm21.54-16.477c0-.375.093-.691.28-.949.188-.258.512-.386.97-.386h4.308c.117 0 .238.03.367.097.13.063.25.152.36.27.113.117.207.258.28.422.079.164.118.347.118.546v26.27c0 .445-.129.785-.379 1.012-.254.23-.578.343-.976.343h-4.079c-.457 0-.78-.113-.968-.343-.188-.227-.282-.567-.282-1.012zm29.609 24.954a11.67 11.67 0 0 1-3.48 2.222c-1.29.535-2.657.801-4.098.801-1.606 0-3.121-.293-4.551-.879a11.8 11.8 0 0 1-3.766-2.437 11.656 11.656 0 0 1-2.566-3.664c-.633-1.407-.95-2.938-.95-4.59 0-1.032.126-2.032.38-3 .25-.965.609-1.871 1.07-2.715a11.743 11.743 0 0 1 1.687-2.332 10.792 10.792 0 0 1 4.899-2.996c.96-.282 1.976-.422 3.043-.422.972 0 1.914.129 2.832.387a11.04 11.04 0 0 1 4.781 2.777 11.35 11.35 0 0 1 1.723 2.156c.48.777.851 1.61 1.117 2.496.262.883.394 1.797.394 2.735 0 .609-.007 1.105-.027 1.492-.016.387-.105.695-.27.926-.164.226-.437.386-.82.472-.379.09-.941.133-1.68.133h-12.66c.118.75.356 1.379.715 1.883.356.504.77.906 1.238 1.203.47.3.97.512 1.497.64a6.294 6.294 0 0 0 1.492.196c.422 0 .855-.043 1.3-.133a8.748 8.748 0 0 0 1.293-.351 7.331 7.331 0 0 0 1.145-.508c.344-.196.625-.399.836-.61.187-.152.348-.265.48-.34a.86.86 0 0 1 .434-.117c.152 0 .309.055.465.16.16.106.336.258.535.458l1.863 2.109c.13.152.211.289.246.414.036.121.055.25.055.379a.977.977 0 0 1-.195.605c-.13.168-.281.32-.457.45zm-8.457-14.649c-.457 0-.899.09-1.328.274-.426.18-.829.421-1.204.726a6.37 6.37 0 0 0-1.011 1.04 6.486 6.486 0 0 0-.73 1.179h8.988a10.599 10.599 0 0 0-.801-1.266 5.564 5.564 0 0 0-.985-1.023 4.295 4.295 0 0 0-1.265-.684c-.477-.164-1.031-.246-1.664-.246zm0 0" />
          </g>
        </svg>
      </div>
    </header>

    <section>
      <div class="left">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 700 510">
          <defs>
            <rect id="b" width="657.638" height="410.833" rx="13.701" />
            <filter x="-1.6%" y="-2.6%" width="103.2%" height="105.1%" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" id="a">
              <feOffset in="SourceAlpha" result="shadowOffsetOuter1" />
              <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="3.5" in="shadowOffsetOuter1" result="shadowBlurOuter1" />
              <feColorMatrix values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.145098039 0 0 0 0 0.180392157 0 0 0 0.181838768 0"
                in="shadowBlurOuter1" />
            </filter>
            <path d="M13.7 0h630.237c7.567 0 13.7 6.134 13.7 13.7v30.122H0V13.701C0 6.134 6.134 0 13.7 0z" id="d" />
            <filter x="-1.6%" y="-24%" width="103.2%" height="147.9%" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" id="c">
              <feOffset in="SourceAlpha" result="shadowOffsetOuter1" />
              <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="3.5" in="shadowOffsetOuter1" result="shadowBlurOuter1" />
              <feColorMatrix values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.145098039 0 0 0 0 0.180392157 0 0 0 0.181838768 0"
                in="shadowBlurOuter1" />
            </filter>
            <linearGradient x1="14.811%" y1="-22.362%" x2="75.996%" y2="119.406%" id="e">
              <stop stop-color="#FAD961" offset="0%" />
              <stop stop-color="#FF52C1" offset="100%" />
            </linearGradient>
            <linearGradient x1="50%" y1="0%" x2="50%" y2="100%" id="f">
              <stop stop-color="#00C7FA" offset="0%" />
              <stop stop-color="#007DFA" offset="100%" />
            </linearGradient>
            <linearGradient x1="28.973%" y1="0%" x2="90.2%" y2="111.244%" id="g">
              <stop stop-color="#FF52C1" offset="0%" />
              <stop stop-color="#9952FF" offset="100%" />
            </linearGradient>
            <path
              d="M11.691 0h195.83c6.457 0 11.692 5.234 11.692 11.691v327.195c0 6.457-5.235 11.692-11.692 11.692H11.691C5.234 350.578 0 345.343 0 338.886V11.691C0 5.234 5.234 0 11.691 0z"
              id="i" />
            <filter x="-4.1%" y="-2.6%" width="108.2%" height="105.1%" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" id="h">
              <feOffset in="SourceAlpha" result="shadowOffsetOuter1" />
              <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="3" in="shadowOffsetOuter1" result="shadowBlurOuter1" />
              <feColorMatrix values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.145098039 0 0 0 0 0.180392157 0 0 0 0.181838768 0"
                in="shadowBlurOuter1" />
            </filter>
            <path d="M11.691 0h195.83c6.457 0 11.692 5.234 11.692 11.691v25.704H0V11.691C0 5.234 5.234 0 11.691 0z"
              id="k" />
            <filter x="-4.1%" y="-24.1%" width="108.2%" height="148.1%" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" id="j">
              <feOffset in="SourceAlpha" result="shadowOffsetOuter1" />
              <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="3" in="shadowOffsetOuter1" result="shadowBlurOuter1" />
              <feColorMatrix values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.145098039 0 0 0 0 0.180392157 0 0 0 0.181838768 0"
                in="shadowBlurOuter1" />
            </filter>
          </defs>
          <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
            <g transform="translate(7 7)">
              <use fill="#000" filter="url(#a)" xlink:href="#b" />
              <use fill="#FFF" xlink:href="#b" />
              <use fill="#000" filter="url(#c)" xlink:href="#d" />
              <use fill="#00252E" xlink:href="#d" />
              <rect fill="#E1E8EE" x="49.323" y="13.694" width="137.008" height="16.433" rx="3.425" />
              <g transform="translate(591.874 15.064)" fill="#D8D8D8">
                <rect width="21.921" height="2.739" rx="1.369" />
                <rect y="5.478" width="21.921" height="2.739" rx="1.369" />
                <rect y="10.956" width="21.921" height="2.739" rx="1.369" />
              </g>
              <g transform="translate(49.323 94.492)">
                <ellipse fill="url(#e)" cx="32.882" cy="32.867" rx="32.882" ry="32.867" />
                <g transform="translate(104.126 8.217)" fill="#E1E8EE">
                  <rect width="78.78" height="10.956" rx="2.055" />
                  <rect y="21.911" width="274.016" height="5.478" rx="2.055" />
                  <rect y="32.867" width="251.181" height="5.478" rx="2.055" />
                  <rect y="43.822" width="228.346" height="5.478" rx="2.055" />
                </g>
                <g transform="translate(411.024 24.65)" fill="#A7B9C8">
                  <ellipse cx="8.22" cy="8.217" rx="8.22" ry="8.217" />
                  <ellipse cx="52.063" cy="8.217" rx="8.22" ry="8.217" />
                  <ellipse cx="30.142" cy="8.217" rx="8.22" ry="8.217" />
                  <ellipse cx="73.984" cy="8.217" rx="8.22" ry="8.217" />
                  <ellipse cx="95.906" cy="8.217" rx="8.22" ry="8.217" />
                </g>
              </g>
              <g transform="translate(49.323 187.614)">
                <ellipse fill="url(#f)" cx="30.827" cy="30.813" rx="30.827" ry="30.813" />
                <g transform="translate(102.07 6.162)" fill="#E1E8EE">
                  <rect width="78.78" height="10.956" rx="2.055" />
                  <rect y="21.911" width="274.016" height="5.478" rx="2.055" />
                  <rect y="32.867" width="251.181" height="5.478" rx="2.055" />
                  <rect y="43.822" width="228.346" height="5.478" rx="2.055" />
                </g>
                <g transform="translate(408.969 22.596)" fill="#A7B9C8">
                  <ellipse cx="8.22" cy="8.217" rx="8.22" ry="8.217" />
                  <ellipse cx="52.063" cy="8.217" rx="8.22" ry="8.217" />
                  <ellipse cx="30.142" cy="8.217" rx="8.22" ry="8.217" />
                </g>
              </g>
              <g transform="translate(49.323 285.53)">
                <ellipse fill="url(#g)" cx="30.827" cy="30.813" rx="30.827" ry="30.813" />
                <g transform="translate(102.07 6.162)" fill="#E1E8EE">
                  <rect width="78.78" height="10.956" rx="2.055" />
                  <rect y="21.911" width="274.016" height="5.478" rx="2.055" />
                  <rect y="32.867" width="251.181" height="5.478" rx="2.055" />
                  <rect y="43.822" width="228.346" height="5.478" rx="2.055" />
                </g>
                <g transform="translate(408.969 22.596)" fill="#A7B9C8">
                  <ellipse cx="8.22" cy="8.217" rx="8.22" ry="8.217" />
                  <ellipse cx="52.063" cy="8.217" rx="8.22" ry="8.217" />
                  <ellipse cx="30.142" cy="8.217" rx="8.22" ry="8.217" />
                  <ellipse cx="73.984" cy="8.217" rx="8.22" ry="8.217" />
                </g>
              </g>
            </g>
            <g transform="translate(483.787 149.422)">
              <use fill="#000" filter="url(#h)" xlink:href="#i" />
              <use fill="#FFF" xlink:href="#i" />
            </g>
            <g transform="translate(483.787 149.422)">
              <use fill="#000" filter="url(#j)" xlink:href="#k" />
              <use fill="#00252E" xlink:href="#k" />
            </g>
            <g transform="translate(505.8 162.277)">
              <rect fill="#E1E8EE" width="71.244" height="14.023" rx="2.923" />
              <g transform="translate(155.111 1.169)" fill="#D8D8D8">
                <rect width="18.706" height="2.337" rx="1.169" />
                <rect y="4.674" width="18.706" height="2.337" rx="1.169" />
                <rect y="9.349" width="18.706" height="2.337" rx="1.169" />
              </g>
            </g>
            <g transform="translate(505.709 223.372)">
              <ellipse fill="url(#e)" cx="10.276" cy="10.271" rx="10.276" ry="10.271" />
              <g transform="translate(31.512 2.054)" fill="#E1E8EE">
                <rect width="39.39" height="3.652" rx=".63" />
                <rect y="7.304" width="137.008" height="1.826" rx=".63" />
                <rect y="10.956" width="125.591" height="1.826" rx=".63" />
                <rect y="14.607" width="114.173" height="1.826" rx=".63" />
              </g>
            </g>
            <g transform="translate(505.709 317.864)">
              <ellipse fill="url(#e)" cx="10.276" cy="10.271" rx="10.276" ry="10.271" />
              <g transform="translate(31.512 2.054)" fill="#E1E8EE">
                <rect width="39.39" height="3.652" rx=".63" />
                <rect y="7.304" width="137.008" height="1.826" rx=".63" />
                <rect y="10.956" width="125.591" height="1.826" rx=".63" />
                <rect y="14.607" width="114.173" height="1.826" rx=".63" />
              </g>
            </g>
            <g transform="translate(505.709 254.87)">
              <g transform="translate(31.512 2.054)" fill="#E1E8EE">
                <rect width="39.39" height="3.652" rx=".63" />
                <rect y="7.304" width="137.008" height="1.826" rx=".63" />
                <rect y="10.956" width="125.591" height="1.826" rx=".63" />
                <rect y="14.607" width="114.173" height="1.826" rx=".63" />
              </g>
              <ellipse fill="url(#f)" cx="10.276" cy="10.271" rx="10.276" ry="10.271" />
            </g>
            <g transform="translate(505.709 349.361)">
              <g transform="translate(31.512 2.054)" fill="#E1E8EE">
                <rect width="39.39" height="3.652" rx=".63" />
                <rect y="7.304" width="137.008" height="1.826" rx=".63" />
                <rect y="10.956" width="125.591" height="1.826" rx=".63" />
                <rect y="14.607" width="114.173" height="1.826" rx=".63" />
              </g>
              <ellipse fill="url(#f)" cx="10.276" cy="10.271" rx="10.276" ry="10.271" />
            </g>
            <g transform="translate(505.709 286.367)">
              <g transform="translate(31.512 2.054)" fill="#E1E8EE">
                <rect width="39.39" height="3.652" rx=".63" />
                <rect y="7.304" width="137.008" height="1.826" rx=".63" />
                <rect y="10.956" width="125.591" height="1.826" rx=".63" />
                <rect y="14.607" width="114.173" height="1.826" rx=".63" />
              </g>
              <ellipse fill="url(#g)" cx="10.276" cy="10.271" rx="10.276" ry="10.271" />
            </g>
            <g transform="translate(505.709 380.858)">
              <g transform="translate(31.512 2.054)" fill="#E1E8EE">
                <rect width="39.39" height="3.652" rx=".63" />
                <rect y="7.304" width="137.008" height="1.826" rx=".63" />
                <rect y="10.956" width="125.591" height="1.826" rx=".63" />
                <rect y="14.607" width="114.173" height="1.826" rx=".63" />
              </g>
              <ellipse fill="url(#g)" cx="10.276" cy="10.271" rx="10.276" ry="10.271" />
            </g>
            <g transform="translate(505.709 412.356)">
              <ellipse fill="url(#e)" cx="10.276" cy="10.271" rx="10.276" ry="10.271" />
              <g transform="translate(31.512 2.054)" fill="#E1E8EE">
                <rect width="39.39" height="3.652" rx=".63" />
                <rect y="7.304" width="137.008" height="1.826" rx=".63" />
                <rect y="10.956" width="125.591" height="1.826" rx=".63" />
                <rect y="14.607" width="114.173" height="1.826" rx=".63" />
              </g>
            </g>
            <g transform="translate(505.709 443.853)">
              <g transform="translate(31.512 2.054)" fill="#E1E8EE">
                <rect width="39.39" height="3.652" rx=".63" />
                <rect y="7.304" width="137.008" height="1.826" rx=".63" />
                <rect y="10.956" width="125.591" height="1.826" rx=".63" />
                <rect y="14.607" width="114.173" height="1.826" rx=".63" />
              </g>
              <ellipse fill="url(#f)" cx="10.276" cy="10.271" rx="10.276" ry="10.271" />
            </g>
          </g>
        </svg>
      </div>
      <div class="right">
        <h1 class="heading"><span class="top">Build The Community</span><span class="bottom">Your Fans Will Love</span>
        </h1>
        <h2 class="sub-heading">
          Huddle re-imagines the way we build communities. You have a voice, but so does your audience.
          Create connections with your users as you engage in genuine discussion.
        </h2>
        <a href="https://matheustenorio.com#contact" class="button" target="_blank">Register</a>
      </div>
    </section>

    <footer>
      <ul>
        <li class="social-icons"><i class="fa-brands fa-github"></i></li>
        <li class="social-icons"><i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i></li>
        <li class="social-icons"><i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-up-right-from-square"></i></li>
      </ul>
    </footer>
  </main>

</body>

</html>
```